# Xcode backward compatibility

Tags: ios, xcode, backwards-compatibility

I have built an app whose target iOS version is iOS 5.1 and my device's version is 6.1.3. However, I cannot make my app run on my device, as I get the following error:

> "No provisioned iOS devices are available with a compatible iOS version. Connect an iOS device with a recent enough version of iOS to run your application or choose an iOS simulator as the destination."

I was expecting the app could run on any device with a iOS version higher than my target version, as that is the case in Android development.

Seems like the only solution is to update my Xcode (currently 4.3.3) but some bad review stating the crash issue on new Xcode(4.6) really put me off.

---

More information from the Organizer:

```
The version of iOS on “Pierr's iPhone” does not match any 
of the versions of iOS supported for development with this 
installation of the iOS SDK. Please restore the device 
to a version of the OS listed below, or update to the latest
version of the iOS SDK; which is available here.

    OS Installed on Pierr's iPhone
    6.1.3 (10B329)

    Xcode Supported iOS Versions
    Latest
    5.1 (9B176)
    5.0
    4.3
    4.2
```

Comment: I use Xcode 4.6.1 every day and it has only crashed on me once. Don't worry about upgrading (though I am still using Lion, not Mountain Lion).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update Xcode to keep it compatible with new iOS versions. The current Xcode version is `4.6.1`.